# Can`t attach image to a multiple posts

Tags: posts, customization, attachments

It seems this question was asked multiple times in the past, but what is the current situation. Is the attachment of an image to a multiple posts possble? Right now when i attach image to more than one posts, the images are assigned to the latest post and removed from the others. Is this the default Wordpress behavior? I have used some Wordpress templates that is possible to attach image to multiple posts. Is it possible that they are using some plugins or the devs have fix it for the template?

Comment: No, this isn't default WordPress behaviour, assuming you're meaning setting the image as the featured image, or adding an image to a post. Try disabling all your plugins, and changing your theme to the Twenty-Twenty Four theme to see if the problem still occurs.